# Tinymce select text

Tags: tinymce, watir-webdriver

I am new to ruby and watir-webdriver.  I am trying to learn how to test tinymce from the website http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php.  I can click the buttons such as "Bold" but I cannot figure out if there is a way to select/highlight text in the textarea to test the "Bold" button.  I can find the text "Feel free" in the textarea but I am not sure how to select the text.  I have noticed that the other posts mention that Tinymce is in frames but it does not appeart to be in a frame on the current page.

Here is what the section looks like (edited form)

```
<textarea id="content" style="width: 100%; height: 550px; display: none;" name="content" cols="20" rows="20" aria-hidden="true">
 <p>Feel free to try out the different features ...</p>
</textarea>


require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b.goto "http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php"

b.div(:id => 'main').wait_until_present
b.textarea(:value => /Feel free/).exists? #this evaluates to "true"

Where I need to select the text

b.a(:title => 'Bold (Ctrl+B)').hover
b.a(:title => 'Bold (Ctrl+B)').click
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the editor is in a frame. This selects `to` from `Welcome to the TinyMCE editor demo!`:

```
require "watir-webdriver"

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto "http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php"

require "watir-webdriver/extensions/select_text"
browser.frame(id:"content_ifr").h1.select_text "to"
```

Comment: I must have had firebug setup wrong.  It is now showing me the iframe on the page.  I also was not aware select_text was an extension that needed to be loaded.  The code is now bolding the text that I have selected.  I guess I need to find some good tutorials on the subject.